# Sorting algorithm with quadratic and linear runtime

Tags: algorithm, sorting, input, runtime

Is it possible to make a sorting algorithm

That its running time at worst case is quadratic => n^2

But in most cases

(That is, on more than half of the n-size inputs)

the run time will be linear => n ??

I was thinking about Radix Sort and just make the worst case, worse

But I do not know if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, the Bucket Sort

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bucket-sort-2/?ref=lbp

you can reed abut the algorithm in the link

In the worst case, we could have a bucket which contains all n values of the
array. Since insertion sort has worst case running time O(n^2), so does Bucket
sort. We can avoid this by using merge sort to sort each bucket instead, which
has worst case running time O(n lg n).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Bucket sort [analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort#Analysis) does reveal such behaviour (with reasonable number of buckets).